# why does my function always return false?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, isset

why does my function always return false?
i think the problem is caused by the isset function but i really dont know how to fix it

```
$big = array(
2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23
,29,31,37);

$fbig = array_flip ($big);


function isprime($n){
    if($n < 2){
        return FALSE;
    }
    if($n > 2147483647){
        return FALSE;
    }
    if($n < 46341){ 
        if(isset($fbig[$n])){


            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}

$b = 11;
if(isprime($b)){echo "lol";}
```

Comment: where is `$fbig` in your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($fbig[$n])){
```

This line is the problem.

1. What you want to check is not `isset($fbig[$n])` (which checks if there is something in the array at the index `$n`) but `in_array($n, $fbig)` (which checks if the array `$fbig` contains the value `$n`).
2. The array `$fbig` is not in the scope of the function since it's defined outside. But you can pass it:

`if(isprime($b, $fbig)){echo "lol";}`

should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

because your looking for a key, not a value

`$fbig[11]` is not set

you'll want to use `in_array()`

in this case, there are 11 items, but they are numbered from 0-10, no 11

plus, like Sarfraz said, it needs to be global

Answer (score 0):

It's because your function doesn't know what $fbig is. A quick fix would be to change your function to look like this:

```
function isprime($n){

    global $fbig;

    if($n < 2){
        return FALSE;
    }
    if($n > 2147483647){
        return FALSE;
    }
    if($n < 46341){ 
         return isset($fbig[$n]); // Nit picking fix!
    }
}
```

Comment: Your 'Nit picking fix' is great but `in_array()` should have been used instead of `isset()` as described by cgoddard